# C# : RedisCache Manager changing database number

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am using RedisCache for caching the data in c# application. so while configuring the RedisCache in app.config , we are setting the database='0', so if we change the database to other number between 1 to 15, its always taking 0 as default  (ie) db0 as default.

Is there any way to change the Database number.

```
 <redisCacheClient allowAdmin="false" ssl="false" connectTimeout="3000"  poolSize = "5" 
  database="2" syncTimeout ="1000" abortOnConnectFail="true">
  <serverEnumerationStrategy mode="All" targetRole="Any" 
     unreachableServerAction="IgnoreIfOtherAvailable" />
    <hosts>
    <add host="localhost" cachePort="6379" />
   </hosts>
   </redisCacheClient>
```

Thanks,

Raajesh K A